# iptables,how to flush / shutdown firewall correctly?

Tags: iptables

I want to flush all iptables firewall chains,i use this script..
for shutdown.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t nat -Z
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t mangle -Z
iptables -t nat --delete-chain
iptables -t mangle --delete-chain
```

But doesn't work,for example,ping is blocked

After do this script iptables -L seems ok...

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

edit: was not ok..  input is drop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

I modify the script like this

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t nat -Z
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t mangle -Z
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t raw -Z
```